# IKVM version 8.1.5717.0 Critical Error when called from LabView 2012

Tags: java, c#, labview, ikvm

We're trying to run the DLL that was generated by IKVM.net (merged using ilmerge) but we keep on getting this failure error.

Note: I already raised this issue with IKVM but I wanted to ask this here as well.

---

### IKVM.NET 8.1.5717.0 Critical Failure

** Critical Failure: Failed to find core classes in core library **

PLEASE FILE A BUG REPORT FOR IKVM.NET WHEN YOU SEE THIS MESSAGE

(on Windows you can use Ctrl+C to copy the contents of this message to the clipboard)

NeutoSpfsLibrary, Version=8.1.5717.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\

4.0.30319.42000 32-bit

at IKVM.Internal.JVM.CriticalFailure(String message, Exception x)

at IKVM.Internal.ClassLoaderWrapper.LoadRemappedTypes()

at IKVM.Internal.ClassLoaderWrapper..cctor()

at IKVM.Internal.ClassLoaderWrapper.IsRemappedType(Type type)

at IKVM.NativeCode.ikvm.runtime.Util.GetTypeWrapperFromObject(Object o)

at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Object[] original, Int32 newLength)

at java.util.ArrayList.grow(Int32 )

at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(Int32 )

at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(Int32 )

at java.util.ArrayList.add(Object e)

at io.neuto.client.main.PublishApiTest1.generateDataHashAndSign(String messageType, String senderPrivateKey, String receiverPublicKey, File file)

at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)

at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)

at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)

at NationalInstruments.LabVIEW.DNRuntime.InvokeMethod(Int32 invokeType, Type type, ObjectId objectId, String methodName, Type[] parameterTypes, Int32[] parameterFlags, ObjectId[]& parameterIds)

at NationalInstruments.LabVIEW.CrossDomainServer.DNInvokeMethod(Int32 invokeType, LVAssembly* lvAssembly, Char* typeName, Int32 objectId, Char* methodName, Int32 numParams, LVAssembly** paramTypeAssemblies, Char** paramTypeNames, Int32* paramFlagArray, Int32* paramDataArray, LStr*** errStrOut)

---

### OK

Any clues or leads or ideas how we can resolve this? I'm using Visual Studio 2015, compiled the c# library using .net 3.5. My Java API (converted to DLL) was compiled using Java 8 (which is compatible with IKVM 8.x).

Thank you.

Comment: I'm no expert on this but I expect people will want to know whether you've tried creating and calling a minimal example DLL with the same result? In any case this is a question I would take to the NI forums.

Comment: I already raised this to the official sourceforge page of IKVM. I ended up writing a C# class library from scratch.

Comment: 2 years later, but this is common enough with IKVM that it should have an answer. Just a few questions: Are all of the IKVM dll files referenced in your .NET project? Does the generated .dll version match what your project expects? Is the java src and its dependencies organized correctly?

Comment: Had the same error after trying to build a self-contained Transform.exe from http://www.saxonica.com/. I used first ILMerge then ILRepack to build this with no errors, but the resulting Transform.exe does not run but shows the exception above.